# Disable auto uploading with Filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

Is there a way to disable auto uploading with Filepicker.io? I'd like to be able to select a couple of files and then explicitly click an 'Upload' button to being the upload process. This would be especially handy for the pickMultiple function as users may want to select files from various folders on their system.

Comment: Filepicker engineer here. Sorry we don't have that at the moment on the local uploads side.

Comment: Thank Liyan. I will close this question so that it doesn't float in Unanswered limbo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Liyan in the above comment, this is currently not possible with their API.